# Is it possible to load a dynamic website and trigger a search field inside of it?

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi and I want to know, is it technically possible to perform this task?

[image: Concept image]

Firstly, I want to load a dynamic website, and then search it using an external input field, as in the picture.

When I enter a search parameter in the left side, it should perform a search operation in the loaded website.

Comment: Is it technically possible? Yes. Question answered. Oh, you wanted more details? Then you should be more specific in your questioning.

Comment: This is also possible for static websites.

Comment: Do you need to display the site to the user or would you be better with a headless browser

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I need to show the data to users.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To be specific, I want to enter search parameter in custom input field and after clicking search button it should pass that value to dynamic website (right side) and show the result.

Comment: Which site are you talking here about? DO you know that some sites include search pattern in their URL. For instance here is a stack overflow URL after entering  _this is a test search query_ into its search field `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=this+is+a+test+search+query`. So perhaps you could just modify the site URL appropriately in order to include your search pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically possible.

On the right side of your application window, you should drop a [TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Building_a_VCL_Forms_Web_Browser_Application) (This is actually based on Internet Explorer) or the new [TEdgeBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Edge.TEdgeBrowser).

You can then use those component's methods to make them load the page you want to.